# The interpretation of 'at least one' event in probability

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

In the following question, I don't understand why combination such as {20,19,18} is not even considered? Or it's already implied in some of the calculation below implicitly? (but it's not clear to me, please point out if so). And why not 1-something is used in this case? Or, is the definition of random variable X as the largest value among the 3 picked ball a wrong way of definition to begin with? (Should we just declare 3 separate random variables for each of the picking trial instead? If so, how?)

Thanks in advance! :)

[image]

Comment: The combination $\{20,19,18\}$ is considered implicitly. $X$ is defined as the *largest* number of the three numbers selected. The outcome where the three draws are $\{20,19,18\}$ is just one of the outcomes where $X=20$. There are ${19}\choose{2}$ outcomes in which $X=20$, because there is 1 choice for the highest number ball, the ball with number 20, and then ${19}\choose{2}$ ways to choose the other two balls.

Comment: @Isaac, ah it makes sense now. Thanks! I think it's quite difficult to come up with the definition of random variable sometimes, like in this case it's defined as X being the largest number among the 3 picked. Is there any tips and tricks for properly defining the random variable X?

Answer (score 1):

The outcome in which the three balls drawn are, in descending order, $\{20, 19, 18\}$, is counted in the event $X = 20$, since this event explicitly includes the following outcomes:

$$\color{red}{\{20, 19, 18\}}, \{20, 19, 17\}, \{20, 19, 16\}, \ldots, \{20, 19, 1\}, \\
\{20, 18, 17\}, \{20, 18, 16\}, \ldots, \{20, 18, 1\}, \\
\ldots, \\
\{20, 2, 1\}.
$$

Note again that these are all sorted in decreasing order.

As to your second question, we certainly can do the calculation with the complementary event, and in fact, I would argue that this is the easier method.  The complementary event is that none of the numbers drawn exceed $16$.  So the probability of such an outcome is

$$\frac{\binom{16}{3}}{\binom{20}{3}} = \frac{28}{57},$$

and the desired probability is $$1 - \frac{28}{57} = \frac{29}{57} \approx 0.508772,$$

which agrees with the result in the book.  This would have been my first method to try.

Regarding your last question, which I have interpreted as "Can we use some other random variable to count the desired outcomes," the answer is again yes.  We can, for instance, let $Y$ count the number of balls that were drawn that are in the set $\{17, 18, 19, 20\}$.  Then $Y$ has a hypergeometric distribution with probability mass function

$$\Pr[Y = y] = \frac{\binom{4}{y}\binom{20-4}{3-y}}{\binom{20}{3}}, \quad y \in \{0, 1, 2, 3\}.$$

Then the probability that $Y \ge 1$, is the desired probability, and we can compute this either directly via the sum

$$\Pr[Y \ge 1] = \sum_{y=1}^3 \Pr[Y = y],$$

or again by the complement:

$$\Pr[Y \ge 1] = 1 - \Pr[Y = 0].$$

Note that the latter approach is exactly equivalent to the computation I showed earlier.